# How to get innerhtml of child span of element by ID javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my html, I need to get the innerhtml value of the span class that is a child of a div class.

```
<div id="id1" class="topdiv" entity="id1">
    <div class="topmiddiv">
        <p class="topmiddiv">
            <span class="topmiddiv">Text Here</span>
```

My first thought was the JS I have below but the span class I am looking for does not always have the same index. Is there any way to get the first span child?

```
document.getElementById("id1").childNodes[2].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use vanilla JS for this task

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id1 span.topmiddiv')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: In a single call you wouldn't notice any difference @Tushar

Answer (score 3):

As you're using jQuery.

```
$('#id1 span.topmiddiv').html()
```

This will find the `<span>` having class `topmiddiv` element inside `#id1` and return its `innerHTML`.

Demo:

```js
alert($('#id1 span.topmiddiv').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="topdiv" entity="id1">
  <div class="topmiddiv">
    <p class="topmiddiv">
      <span class="topmiddiv">Text Here</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Vanilla Javascript, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
alert(document.querySelector('#id1 span.topmiddiv').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="topdiv" entity="id1">
  <div class="topmiddiv">
    <p class="topmiddiv">
      <span class="topmiddiv">Text Here</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use this as your selector  :

```
$("span.topmiddiv").html();
```